# How to read incoming slack messages?

Tags: python, slack, slack-api

A report is posted every 5 hrs on a Slack channel, from which we need to sort/filter some information and put it into a file.

So, is there any way to read the channel continuously or run some command every 5 minutes or so before that time, and capture the report for future processing?

Comment: Is this on a linux system, if so, use cron

Comment: Yes this is on Linux but can you share the command which can view the slack message so that we can use cron.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that is possible. Here is the basic outline of a solution:

- Create a Slack app based on a script (e.g. in Python) that has access to
  that channel's history (e.g. has the [`channels:history`](https://api.slack.com/scopes/channels:history) permission scope)
- Use cron to call your script at the needed time
- The script reads the channels history (e.g. with [`channel.history`](https://api.slack.com/methods/channels.history) for public channels), filterers out what it needs
  and then stores the report as file.

Another approach would be to continuously read every new message from the channel, parse for a trigger (e.g. a specific user that sends it or the name of the report) and then filter and safe the report when it appears. If you can identify a reliable trigger this would in my experience be the more stable solution, since scheduled reports can be delayed.

For that approach use the [Events API of Slack](https://api.slack.com/events-api) instead of CRON and subscribe to receiving messages (e.g. [message](https://api.slack.com/events/message) event for public channels). Slack will then automatically send each new message to your script as soon as it is posted.

If you are new to creating Slack apps I would advise to study the excellent [official documentation](https://api.slack.com/) and [tutorials](https://api.slack.com/tutorials) on the Slack API site to get started.

Comment: If we create the app for reading the channel, where is the file getting stored  on the slack server or on the client machine, will there be any manual intervention.

Comment: That will depend on where your Slack app chooses to store it. Assuming your slack app comprises of a python script running on your linux box you would probably store it on the linux box.Or you can use the script to submit the report somewhere else. Theoretically it could also submit the new report to a channel on your Slack if required. 
There should be no need for manual intervention if the script is done well.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know Python. Also, stackoverfow is not a coding service, but a forum for people who code. Check Slack tutorials or github for examples on how it works. Feel free to post here again if you need help for an existing piece of your code.

Answer (score 2):

A Python example to this approach could be found here: https://gist.github.com/demmer/617afb2575c445ba25afc432eb37583b

This script counts the amount of messages per user.

Based on this code I created the following example for you:

```
# get the correct channel id
for channel in channels['channels']:
    if channel['name'] == channel_name:
        channel_id = channel['id']
if channel_id == None:
    raise Exception("cannot find channel " + channel_name)

# get the history as follows: 
history = sc.api_call("channels.history", channel=channel_id)

# get all the messages from the history: 
messages = history['messages']

# Or reference them by ID, so in this case get the first message:
ids = messages[0]
```